# GNU screen doesn't work in Cygwin -- directory must have mode 700

Tags: permissions, gnu-screen, cygwin

I installed Cygwin on Windows 10 and `screen` fails with

```
$ screen
Directory '/tmp/uscreens' must have mode 777.
```

I couldn't change the permissions for whatever reason

```
$ chmod -R 777 /tmp
$ ls -hal /tmp/uscreens
total 384K
drwxr-xr-x 1 username Domain Users 0 May 22 17:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 username Domain Users 0 Jul 17 15:54 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 username Domain Users 0 May 22 17:37 S-username
```

so I created a new directory that I have full control over, but got permission problems again:

```
$ SCREENDIR=/cygdrive/e/screens ./screen.exe
Directory /cygdrive/e/screens must have mode 700.
$ ls -hal /cygdrive/e/screens
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 1 username Domain Users 0 Jul 17 16:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 username Domain Users 0 Jul 17 16:23 ..
```

I also tried removing the r-xr-x permissions in the Windows Explorer world (and there it now says that really only the user has access at all) but in Cygwin's view it's still the same and I can still not use screen.

Comment: What kind of filesystem /tmp is on?

Comment: @Janka it is on an NTFS

Comment: Right click on icon you use to launch Cygwin and choose "Run as administrator" then try changing `/tmp/uscreens` permissions from there. If it worked go back to a normal terminal (w/o administrator privileges) and try `screen`.

Comment: @BLayer didnt work (chmod was still uneffective with admin rights)

Comment: Does `chmod` work anywhere? Does your user account belong to/own the Domain group? See if changing to group Users or None helps (`chgrp -R xxx` on the parent dir, e.g.... test in dummy dirs first.)

Comment: @BLayer Chmod does work In some places. I don't know how to check what group my user belongs to or who owns what group. Chances are I don't own anything and don't belong to anything in the Cygwin installation directory because it's on a company computer. IT are willing to give me rights to things though so I'll have them try what you suggested after the weekend (unfortunately they have no experience with Cygwin)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and I believe the reason is how the Windows drive is being mounted on your system.

My configuration:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
none                          /cygdrive             cygdrive  binary,posix=0,user,noacl 0 0
```

It's the `noacl` bit that's causing the issue (which we're using for reasons outside the scope of this response). If I run `screen -R` to start up (or reattach) to a screen session, I get your error:

```
$ screen -R
Directory /tmp/uscreens/S-myuser must have mode 700.
$ ls -ld /tmp/uscreens/S-myuser
drwxr-xr-x 1 myuser Domain Users 0 May 13 06:57 /tmp/uscreens/S-myuser/
$ chmod 700  /tmp/uscreens/S-myuser
$ ls -ld /tmp/uscreens/S-myuser
drwxr-xr-x 1 myuser Domain Users 0 May 13 06:57 /tmp/uscreens/S-myuser/
$ cd /tmp
$ pwd -P
/cygdrive/c/tmp
```

As you can see, we have `/tmp` as a symbolic link referring to `C:/tmp` (again, for reasons outside the scope of this response).

The solution is to set the `SCREENDIR` environment variable to refer to a location that is not under `/cygdrive`. For my setup, that was my home directory:

```
$ SCREENDIR=~/.screens screen -R
```

This started up the `screen` session with no problems.

Confirming the folder is not under `/cygdrive`:

```
$ cd ~/.screens && pwd -P
/home/myuser/.screens
$ ls -ld ~/.screens
drwx------+ 1 myuser Domain Users 0 May 13 07:14 /home/myuser/.screens/
```

As you can see, the folder has mode 700, as required by `screen`, and is found under `/home` rather than `/cygdrive`.